# iPhone Theos, audio recording and saving with one button?

Tags: iphone, c++, sdk, audio-recording

i've never been good with c++ but im learning with theos and i waswondering, is there a way to make a button that can start recording audio, then stop when it is pressed again? or even better, could i have it record until the phone detects that you are done talking???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  The combination of a UIButton, one BOOL state variable, and the use of an iOS audio API (there are several, such as the Audio Queue API) will do this.

Comment: could you direct me to an api?